Unit tests randomly fail on ci/cd because of permissionsetgroup status is randomly changing to 'Updating'
Unit tests randomly fail on ci/cd because of permissionsetgroup status is randomly changing to 'Updating'.
We are just assigning permission set group to the user in the preliminary actions before executing the actual test.
insert new PermissionSetAssignment(PermissionSetId = ps.Id, AssigneeId = user.Id);
What might be the reason and how these random unit test failures can be fixed or addressed?
